# trim lines, as with 'cut' BUT correcting for color codes

Tags: scripting

It's easy enough to trim lines:

```
print -l $array | cut -$COLUMNS
```

... but if the lines of the array are colored the cut is wrong because the color codes count towards the width of the line, so in practice the colored line is cut too short.  Is there some off the shelf correction for this?  Crudely, if I have one colorized word in a line I do this:

```
... $(( COLUMNS + 17 ))
```

... but if there were more colorized words of course that would be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You have to somehow count the number of characters used in escape codes, and then add them to your $COLUMNS.

Here's a way to get the count:

```
echo -E $mystring | grep -Eoz '\\e\[[0-9;]+m' | sed -e 's/\x00//g' | wc -m
```

- `echo` args: the `-E` is there to keep the color codes as they are so we can grep them
- `grep` args: the `-E` is to match extended regex, the `-o` is to return only the matched parts of the line, and the `-z` is to replace newlines with `\x00`
- we then use `sed` to strip the `\x00` bytes and finally
- `wc` returns the character count

Ok, let's test it on some example string:

```
mystring='\e[1;31;3mThis is red text, and \e[1;32mthis is green text \e[0m'
echo -E "$mystring" | grep -Eoz '\\e\[[0-9;]+m' | sed -e 's/\x00//g' | wc -m
echo -e "$mystring"
```

Looks good, prints 23 and then the string with coloring applied. Now to build the whole thing:

```
cols=20
mystring='\e[1;31;3mThis is red text, and \e[1;32mthis is green text \e[0m'
# strip the reset escape code from end of the line so it doesn't get counted
mystring=$(echo -E $mystring | sed -e 's/\\e\[0m$//g')
# count the escape codes
countesc=$(echo -E "$mystring" | grep -Eoz '\\e\[[0-9;]+m' | sed -e 's/\x00//g' | wc -m)
# cut the line while accounting for escape codes, and add back the reset escape code to the end
echo -e $(echo -E "$mystring" | cut -b -$((cols+countesc)))"\e[0m"
```

This works if you're cutting after the last color code. Something more complex would have to be built to account for location of color codes.

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be to use gawk (gnu awk, or any new awk that knows how to keep separators in an array on a split) to : split on "escape codes", and compute what real characters needs to be shown.

Assuming: you only have "regular printable characters" apart from escape codes. If you have more complex input, it will need to be taken into account (modify the $color_escape_codes value to add : "|some_other_noncounted_char(s)")

```
len=123  # or $COLUMNS, or whatever you want it to be: the nb of chars to cut at
color_escape_codes="$(  printf '\033['  )[0-9;]+m"
gawk -F"${color_escape_codes}" -v len=$len '
    {
        nf=split( $0, a, FS, seps )
        cur=0
        for( i=1; i<=nf; i++ ) {
            cur=cur + length( a[i] )
            if( cur<=len ) {
              printf( "%s%s", a[i], seps[i] )
                if( (cur==len) || (i==nf) ) {
                    print ""
                    break
                }
            } else {
                printf( "%s\n", substr( a[i], 1, (len-(cur-length(a[i]))) ) )
                break
            }
        }
    }'
```

Comment: probably can be further simplified, I arrived there through iterations. Maybe change the '<=len' by '<len', take out the if for that part ? But I can't verify further at the moment. It can be tricky when you arrive near the length of a given input line

Comment: You also maybe need to add an : \033[0m at the end of every printed lines? which may change the behavior of your coloring (all lines will start with the "normal" color...) but also will avoir a color to "leak" in the next line (ex: you have  : `_green_foo_yellow_bar_normal_` : and cut at `foo` : the next line will start with `_yellow_` at that seps[] was printed as well ... adding a `_normal_` coloring block before calling break will help those cases, but also changes things if you didn't have a "_normal_" block at the end of each line's coloring sections... ymmv)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I ended up doing it.  Rather simple stuff:

Let 'var' be a variable with some color codes in it:

```
lenvar=$#var
stripped=$( echo $var | stripcolors )
lenstripped=$#stripped
(( difference = lenvar - lenstripped ))
((correctedwidth = COLUMNS + difference))
echo $var | cut -c -$correctedwidth
```

... magic ingredient:

```
stripcolors is an alias for sed "s/\x1B\[\([0-9]\{1,2\}\(;[0-9]\{1,2\}\)\?\)\?[mGK]//g"
```